# Can Google Spreadsheets conditionally format based on a previous cells content?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to conditionally format the background colour of a cell, based on the value in the column *preceding* it?

For example, in the following table (first row/column are titles):

```
  | A | B | C
1 | 1 | 5 | 2
2 | 2 | 7 | 0
3 | 3 | 1 | 2
4 | 1 | 3 | 4
5 | 1 | 5 | 0
6 | 4 | 1 | 2
7 | 8 | 2 | 4
```

**B1** should be green, as it is greater than **A1**.

but

**C5** should be red, as it is less than **B1**, etc

I'd like this formatting rule to work with any new column I add. The dataset I'm working with is date driven analytics.

Try as I might, I can either only seem to format the cells by:

- A fixed number
- A fixed cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally format based on another cell or column by selecting your cells, and making a conditional formatting rule for cells "Greater Than" the cell "A1" as shown below.

Sheets uses this as a relative reference that you're comparing the cell to the left of each cell in your selection.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Doh! I was just missing the '='. Thanks @Rob